# Why not to multiply with $g$ when doing sums in the unit $\rm kgf$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, units, dimensional-analysis, buoyancy

My book told me a thing to keep in mind while doing upthrust sums in $\rm kgf$. It's stated as follows: (See point number 2)

[image: Please see the point number 2 in this image]

Can you please explain why not to multiply with $g$?

Also I am giving another sum from my book, which I also couldn't do when I multiplied with g. The sum is:(See Sum No 1)

[image: Kindly see the Numerical No. 1]

I have tried to make my doubt as clear as possible. Please help me.

I will supply any other details needed as well.

Comment: You may want to remove the images and just explain the question, it is very hard to read and understand what is going on here.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused with the term  **1 kgf**. It is used to indicate the force experienced by a body of 1 kg or its weight and its value is obtained by :

$1KgF = 1Kg × g= 1 × 9.8 m/s^2$

So you can see in your second image also that the term *kgF* is used to express the **weight** of the body in air and it already includes the value of *g* . So no need to use it again.

Comment: @S Roy was my answer helpful ? Or something unclear ?